# Tag helper not working with razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am creating a partial view for rendering inputs for a list. The problem is that I need to supply the asp-for attribute with razor code like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
<label asp-for="@ViewData["AspFor"]"></label>
<input asp-for="@ViewData["AspFor"]" value="@Model.FirstOrDefault()">
```

I call the partial using:

```
@Html.Partial("Partial",
  Model.MyList,
  new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData){
    { "AspFor", "MyList" }
  });
```

which renders into:

```
<label for="ViewData_AspFor_">ViewData[AspFor]</label>
<input value="item 1" type="text" id="ViewData_AspFor_" name="ViewData[AspFor]">
```

Is it possible to render the ViewData["AspFor"] value into the asp-for attribute before letting tag helper to render the element?